# Send Email Programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent, logcat

So I am trying to send an email in Android without using Intent because I need it to be sent in the background. I am following [this post](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android),

I have the .jars added as part of the build path.

And I have this code as the class

```
package cistoran.partyPlanner;

import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.activation.CommandMap; 
import javax.activation.DataHandler; 
import javax.activation.DataSource; 
import javax.activation.FileDataSource; 
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap; 
import javax.mail.BodyPart; 
import javax.mail.Multipart; 
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication; 
import javax.mail.Session; 
import javax.mail.Transport; 
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart; 


public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
  private String _user; 
  private String _pass; 

  private String[] _to; 
  private String _from; 

  private String _port; 
  private String _sport; 

  private String _host; 

  private String _subject; 
  private String _body; 

  private boolean _auth; 

  private boolean _debuggable; 

  private Multipart _multipart; 


  public Mail() { 
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

    _user = ""; // username 
    _pass = ""; // password 
    _from = ""; // email sent from 
    _subject = ""; // email subject 
    _body = ""; // email body 

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
  } 

  public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
    this(); 

    _user = user; 
    _pass = pass; 
  } 

  public boolean send() throws Exception { 
    Properties props = _setProperties(); 

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

      InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
      } 
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

      msg.setSubject(_subject); 
      msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
      messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

      // Put parts in message 
      msg.setContent(_multipart); 

      // send email 
      Transport.send(msg); 

      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 

  public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

    if(_debuggable) { 
      props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    } 

    if(_auth) { 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    } 

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

    return props; 
  } 

  // the getters and setters 
  public String getBody() { 
    return _body; 
  } 

  public void setBody(String _body) { 
    this._body = _body; 
  }
  public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
      this._to = toArr;
  }

  public void setFrom(String string) {
      this._from = string;
  }

  public void setSubject(String string) {
      this._subject = string;
  }

  // more of the getters and setters ….. 
}
```

And I have this code as my sendEmail method that is activated by clicking a button in the menu.

```
public void sendEmail()
{
    EditText childNameBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.childNameBox);
    EditText parentNameBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.parentNameBox);
    EditText phoneNumberBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumberBox);
    EditText ageBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageBox);
    EditText notesBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.notesBox);
    EditText colorsBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.colorsBox);
    EditText dateBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateBox);
    EditText timeBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timeBox);

    childName = childNameBox.toString();
    parentName = parentNameBox.toString();
    childAge = ageBox.toString();
    phoneNumber = phoneNumberBox.toString();
    colorChoice = colorsBox.toString();
    notesText = notesBox.toString();
    dateDay = dateBox.toString();
    timeDay = timeBox.toString();

    emailCombined = childName + bN + parentName + bN + childAge + bN + phoneNumber + bN + colorChoice + bN + notesText + bN + dateDay + bN + timeDay;
    Mail m = new Mail("emailaddress", "password"); 

    String[] toArr = {"TOEMAIL@gmail.com.com", "FROMEMAIL@gmail.com"};
    m.setTo(toArr);
    m.setFrom("FROMEMAIL@gmail.com"); 
    m.setSubject("Party Booked"); 
    m.setBody(emailCombined); 

    try { 
      //m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 

      if(m.send()) { 
        Toast.makeText(PartyPlannerActivity.this, "Sent Email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
      } else { 
        Toast.makeText(PartyPlannerActivity.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
      } 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
      //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
      Log.e("PartyPlannerActivity", "Could not send email.", e); 
    } 
}
```

And here is the LogCat I got from it

```
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399): Could not send email.
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399): javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):   nested exception is:
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at cistoran.partyPlanner.Mail.send(Mail.java:104)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at cistoran.partyPlanner.PartyPlannerActivity.sendEmail(PartyPlannerActivity.java:101)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at cistoran.partyPlanner.PartyPlannerActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(PartyPlannerActivity.java:62)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2205)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:748)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:532)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399): Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.socket(Native Method)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.socket(BlockGuard.java:335)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:216)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:802)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:948)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:926)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:163)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1359)
09-01 18:35:50.767: ERROR/PartyPlannerActivity(399):     ... 25 more
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not working for me I Got Error `Could not send email
    javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
            at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
`

Comment: have you face this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the `INTERNET` permission to your manifest.

Comment: Oops, I had it there, it was just in the wrong place inside the file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Did you miss INTERNET permission at your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add the INTERNET permission to your app.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [android.permission.INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission in your [manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) to enable your application to open a network socket.

Answer (score 1):

Insert this code in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```