# how to send confirmation email to the user when registered to the application android

Tags: android, email, registration, verification, forgot-password

I am trying to add this feature in my android app when the user registers I would send an email to their inbox by clicking the link the user would confirm their registration and the same thing for the case when the user forgets the password
Can I do this using SQLite only? or I would need some mySQL and php? Can you guide me through the steps needed to do such thing?

Comment: do it at your server side.....

Comment: after confirm registration, for registration web service called, at your server end, just send a mail to email address(used for registration). For server end programming you need to search on php(you may using this).

Comment: I don't have a web service or a server it's an android app I just want to send a confirmation email from my personal email to the user's email if that's not possible is sending a code over an sms possible?

Comment: ohh, I got wrong, you mean using local registration, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274949/send-email-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: yes that's exactly what I was asking for! Thank you so much but I am getting a NetworkOnMainThread Exception. I used this code to override it.StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);  But I have read that an AsyncTask is a better solution so, what will be the params of the AsyncTask?

Comment: There are lots of tutorial available, Please GOOGLE.

Comment: Just shortly after I asked you I found a solution thank you so much you were a great help

Comment: @Atihska i used the code in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274949/send-email-programmatically-in-android?lq=1 just don't forget to add internet permissions and this link will be useful too http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android and yeah you have to download the libraries and add them to the build path of your app